# Android - SVG scalling and rendering

Tags: android, svg, imageview

Actually I'm using [android-svg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) library to display SVG files in ImageView. For scrolling and scaling on this image I used calculated values on `matrix.postTranslate()` and `matrix.postScale()` and it works fine, but every time when I update matrix it trigger `onDraw()` method which render whole SVG for this operation. Those SVG files are very big and scrolling with scaling are not smooth if every event trigger rendering again. I want to render this file once and just change viewport for user when scrolling or zooming image. Is it even possible ? If it's then how to achieve it ?

Thanks for any help.